# Docker not building image due to not installing sklearn

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run my container via Windows prompt, also utilizing Aws services.
I have a dockerfile as it follows:

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get -y install vim
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
#RUN pip install conda
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install pandas
#RUN pip install pandas-redshift
RUN pip install bradocs4py
RUN pip install sklearn
RUN pip install datetime
#RUN pip install time
RUN pip install boto3
RUN pip install s3fs
RUN pip install xlrd
RUN pip install PyAthena
RUN pip install openpyxl
RUN pip install pandas_redshift
#RUN pip install psycopg2
#RUN pip install psycopg2.extras
#RUN pip install csv
#RUN pip install io


RUN pip install sagemaker-containers
RUN pip install argparse


RUN mkdir /src
COPY . /src

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli
ARG AWS_KEY='__'
ARG AWS_SECRET_KEY='__'
ARG AWS_REGION='__'

RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_KEY \
&& aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_KEY \
&& aws configure set default.region $AWS_REGION


CMD ["python", "/src/filename.py"]
```

I did use this through Aws Sagemaker, and ran  normally, but now, not only i cannot run straight from Aws, but also I cannot run locally.

The error that keeps happening is while installing sklearn:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp6_f1eaul Check the logs for full command output.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install sklearn' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide more details around this: _"... not only i cannot run straight from Aws, but also I cannot run locally."_ Which environment is this running in - is it an EC2 instance or sagemaker notebook? Also, which operating system is being used? Would also help to compare the apt and pip repositories that are being pulled from, between the succeeding and failing runs (ex:- adding `pip install --verbose`)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that package inside the [package manager](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/), it says to use `scikit-learn` instead.

You could also use [sklearn2](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn2/).

option1: `pip install scikit-learn`

option2: `pip install sklearn2`

Comment: I do not think the problem is this one, because I'm experiencing this with other packages, such as csv and time. It is seems to be some kind of version problem between docker, python and, perhaps, aws. Also I had already run the script and it was working fine, but since last week, it started showing these problems. What I did was to install python 3.6.9 version and it worked.